# How to handle encoded data in Textarea

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, antixsslibrary

Using **Antixss library** i have encoded the text and stored in DB. My issue is when i getting the data from DB to show in TextArea its showing as encoded Text. This problem in ASP.Net-MVC4.
How can i decode the data and show in textarea. can any one help this. How can i decode the text using antixss library. or any another way to decode the text.

Answer (score 0):

Use @Html.Raw(data) This would display your data without encoding it.

Comment: i need to show in TextArea for edit the data.             @Html.TextArea("txtNewsDetails_" + Model.AppId, Model.Text, new { cols = 50, rows = 5 })

Comment: Have you tried just wrapping Html.Raw around the Model.Text so @Html.Raw(Model.Text)?

Comment: @Html.TextArea("txtNewsDetails_"+Model.AppId,@Html.Raw(Model.Text), new {cols=50, rows=5)})-----> is syntax error... My requirement is show decoding data in text area for edit the data..

Comment: Can you confirm your issue is the same as the one mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248063/html-decode-and-encode)?